# SharpDX, can't find a function

Tags: sharpdx

I am trying to use the CreateRenderTargetView function since I am transcribing C++ DirectX over to C#.  I am using D3D11.  It there a substitution for CreateRenderTargetView that I could use?

Answer (score 4):

The general philosophy of SharpDX is to move all xxx.CreateYYY(...) to the constructor of new YYY(xxx, ...), so CreateRenderTargetView is in "[new RenderTargetView](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d11-rendertargetview--ctor-2)"